# How to add a vertical line beside list items with css

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive-design

I want to add a vertical red/ yellow colour line after my list items in the sidebar menu.

For the first list item, it's fine, but it's breaking from the second item. The `:after` pseudo-selector doesn't span the entire height. Can someone tell where I am going wrong.

```css
.sidebar {
  background-color: #09204f;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.sidebar img {
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

body {
  margin: 25px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-item {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border: 1px dashed white;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}
.nav-item .kpi-name {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.nav-item .kpi-value {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.nav-item.green-item:after {
  background-color: #15a859;
  border-color: #15a859;
}
.nav-item.amber-item:after {
  background-color: #f8ae0a;
  border-color: #f8ae0a;
}
.nav-item.red-item:after {
  background-color: #e73e46;
  border-color: #e73e46;
}
.nav-item:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 7px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.page {
  background-color: #f3f8ff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrap">


  <div class="sidebar">

    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-item green-item">
          Menu Item



        </li>
        <li class="nav-item amber-item">Menu 2
          <div>
            <span class="kpi-name">
              Active User
            </span>
            <span class="kpi-value">
              2400
            </span>
          </div>

        </li>
        <li class="nav-item green-item ">Menu 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <h1>PAGE CONTENTS HERE</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent element (`li`) needs to be position:relative and the `::after` element needs to be positioned absolutely. Note that I removed the height on the after element - ince at least one of the li's had more than one line within it - and instead applied the top, right, and bottom values to be the same as your padding on the li.

```css
.sidebar {
  background-color: #09204f;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.sidebar img {
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

body {
  margin: 25px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-item {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border: 1px dashed white;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  position: relative
}
.nav-item .kpi-name {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.nav-item .kpi-value {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.nav-item.green-item:after {
  background-color: #15a859;
  border-color: #15a859;
}
.nav-item.amber-item:after {
  background-color: #f8ae0a;
  border-color: #f8ae0a;
}
.nav-item.red-item:after {
  background-color: #e73e46;
  border-color: #e73e46;
}
.nav-item:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.page {
  background-color: #f3f8ff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrap">


  <div class="sidebar">

    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-item green-item">
          Menu Item



        </li>
        <li class="nav-item amber-item">Menu 2
          <div>
            <span class="kpi-name">
              Active User
            </span>
            <span class="kpi-value">
              2400
            </span>
          </div>

        </li>
        <li class="nav-item green-item ">Menu 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <h1>PAGE CONTENTS HERE</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am always confused about this ```position``` property. Please can you suggest any example/ tutorial just to refine my understanding. Appreciate your help!

Comment: no - sorry I on't know of any tutorial for it - probably just google it and you should find something. My knowledge of it comes from using it rather than tutorials. Sorry I cannot be of more help - good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.vl {
  border-left: 6px solid green;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Vertical Line</h2>
<div class="vl"></div>
```

Comment: you should try that it makes a vertical line

Comment: I wanted a rounded line, which was not possible with ```border-left``` or ```border-right``` properties, as it would be difficult the round the top and bottom edge of the border line. I tried a couple of iterations with this actually but none worked.

Comment: Ok will experiment